# SQL aggregate not yielding results

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Why is this giving an empty result? I'm trying to get the min, max, and average of the set of employees who aren't supervisors.

```
SELECT MIN(salary), MAX(salary), AVG(salary)
FROM employee
WHERE ssn NOT IN
(SELECT superssn FROM employee)
```

Part of employee table

```
SSN       SUPERSSN
--------- ---------
888665555
333445555 888665555
987654321 888665555
987987987 987654321
123456789 333445555
999887777 987654321
666884444 333445555
453453453 333445555
```

Comment: what does `Select count(ssn) FROM employee WHERE ssn NOT IN (SELECT superssn FROM employee)`give you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude nulls from the inner query. Otherwise the outer query checks against a list where one of the list values is NULL and that comparison doesn't return anything. So, the correct query should be something like.

```
SELECT MIN(salary), MAX(salary), AVG(salary)
FROM employee
WHERE ssn NOT IN
(SELECT superssn FROM employee where superssn IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: if you select your code and press `{}` you code will be formatted

Answer (score 2):

This is why NOT EXISTS is semantically correct and more reliable

```
SELECT MIN(salary), MAX(salary), AVG(salary)
FROM employee E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM employee E2 WHERE E.ssn = E2.superssn)
```

Any NULL in the NOT IN list will always give false thanks to boolean logic. You have a NULL superssn value.